# VBA on a mail merge - adding a blank page?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Ive got this code to create a bunk of individual pdf's from mail merging on word using an excel list. It's really solid for what i want it to do but it keeps adding a blank page at the end and i can't work out how to remove it?

Can anyone see an error ive made that would add this blank page in or how i could go about removing it?

```
Sub MailMergeToPdfBasic()                                                      

    Dim masterDoc As Document, singleDoc As Document, lastRecordNum As Integer  

    Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument                                               

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord                   
    lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord                  

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord                
    Do While lastRecordNum > 0                                                   

        masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument                    
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord              
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord               
        masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False                                        
        Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument                                           

        singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
            FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument                                      

        singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            OutputFileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF                                      

        singleDoc.Close False                                                    

        If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then    
            lastRecordNum = 0                                                    
        Else
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord           
        End If

    Loop                                                                         

End Sub
```

all help appreciated

Comment: Does it add a blank page, or does it just have an empty paragraph that make the content flow over the page? If so, just delete the empty paragraph.

Comment: It seems to add a blank page, ive made sure there is no text that could flow over

Comment: Given that it is impossible for Word to have an entirely empty page I suggest you click the Show/Hide button on the Home tab and check again.

Comment: I would rename your object from masterDoc to primaryDoc or mainDoc, just to avoid confusion. http://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart